# Image src not displaying external image served by handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a handler that serves images from a external website. This works absolutely fine on its own.

But when I use the handler in an image src attribute it doesn't work.

This is the call I make to the handler:

```
<img src="myhandler.ashx?image=http://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/planetary/venus/gal_venus_37218.jpg" / >
```

This is the code for the handler:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace MumsChoice.Portal.UI.Handlers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class ExternalImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Bitmap bitOutput = null;
            Stream stream = null;
            string contentType = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(context.Request.QueryString["image"]);
                WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
                contentType = response.ContentType;
                stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                bitOutput = new Bitmap(stream);
            }
            catch
            {
                bitOutput.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Close();
                stream.Dispose();
                stream = null;
            }

            ImageFormat format;
            switch (contentType)
            {
                case "image/png":
                    format = ImageFormat.Png;
                    break;
                case "image/gif":
                    format = ImageFormat.Gif;
                    break;
                default:
                    format = ImageFormat.Jpeg;
                    break;
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
            bitOutput.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, format);
            bitOutput.Dispose();
            return;  
        }


        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Check with firebug's NET console, chromes network tab in developer tools or fiddler what the browser actually requests to the server

Comment: Does webconfig knows about new handler? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.processrequest(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I think that you need to check if there is a throw error, to debug to see if you get the image and send it, then if all that works and the issue is on the img tag, in you case I will encode the http:// using URLEncode. Also I will remvoe the WebService and WebServiceBinding this is not belonging to the handler.

Comment: I tried the URLEncode and it didn't make any difference either... the handler does work by itself. it breaks when I add it to the src attribut of the image. Firebug throws an error 500

Comment: Getting a 500 means that your handler threw an exception outside the try block.  My guess is that it also threw one inside the try, never initialized bitOutput (so it is still null) and then throws a null ref. exception when you try to call bitOutput.Dispose or Save.

Comment: Also, see if you can log what your handler gets in the image parameter.  I'm guessing that is somehow the problem.

Comment: I moved all the code inside the try catch and now it works fine. WEIRD

Answer (score -1):

try adding at the end:

```
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: that didn't make a difference